# Vertical scrolling is not working on overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to overlay web pages with some background opacity but when the overlay is applied the web pages vertical scrolling functionality becomes disabled.

jQuery and CSS as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").append("div").attr("id","overlay");

   $("#overlay").css({
       "position" : "fixed",
       "width" : "100%",
       "height" : "100%",
       "z-index" : "10",
       "background": "#000",
       "opacity": "0.5"  
   });

   $("body").css({
      "overflow-y" : "scroll"
   });

});
```

Comment: Careful, this code `$("body").append("div").attr("id","overlay");` gives id attribute to the `body`, not the `div`. I suppose it's not what you want (though your problem may not come from this).

Comment: Then how to append div element as body child with id overlay? I'm facing the problem as you warned. The body is getting the CSS property! @TimothéMalahieude

Comment: Simply do `$("body").append($("div").attr("id","overlay"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippet :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mx03umkr/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").append("div").attr("id","overlay");
$("#overlay").css({
       "position" : "absolute",
       "width" : "100%",
       "height" : "1700px",
       "z-index" : "10",
       "background": "#000",
       "opacity": "0.5"  
    });

    $("body").css({
    "overflow-y" : "scroll"
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```